# lookup doesn't work properly when used with getMappedResults()

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I have the following code, whose answer for the `getRawResult` and `getMappedResult` are different. I would like to know how I can include the `user` and `place` objects in the mappedResults.

```
     // This methd searches the given string in reviews of the given country
                    
        MatchOperation matchRegion = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("Country").is("Germany"));
                    
        //To match the review
        TextCriteria criteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny(text);
        MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(criteria);         

        GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("place.place_name").push("$$ROOT").as("reviews").sum("textScore")
                .as("score");

        ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation
                .project("some_point", "place", "user", "date")
                .andExpression("{$meta: \"textScore\"}").as("textScore");               
    
        SortOperation sortByScore = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "score");

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match,Aggregation.lookup("place","placeId","_id","place"),
                Aggregation.unwind("place"),Aggregation.lookup("user","userId","_id","user"),
                Aggregation.unwind("user") , matchRegion, project, group, sortByScore);

        
        AggregationResults<ReviewAggrResults> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,
                mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Review.class), ReviewAggrResults.class);    
        
        List<ReviewAggrResults> result = results.getMappedResults();
            
        Object object = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Review.class, Object.class).getRawResults();


        Print.print("result object rawResults", object); 
        Print.print("result reviewaggrresult: ", result);
```

With the above code, the printed results for the `getRawResults` and `ReviewAggrResult` are like the following:

Raw Results:

```
  {
      "results" : [ {
        "_id" : "ibis Heidelberg, Willy-Brandt-Platz 3, 69115 Heidelberg, Germany",
        "reviews" : [ {
          "_id" : {
            "timestamp" : 1610817567,
            "date" : 1610817567000
          },
          "some_point" : "something",         
          "date" : "Sat Jan 16 18:19:27 CET 2021",
          "place" : {
            "_id" : {
              "timestamp" : 1610817567,
              "date" : 1610817567000
            },
            "place_name" : "ibis Heidelberg, Willy-Brandt-Platz 3, 69115 Heidelberg, Germany",
            "country" : "Germany",
          },
          "user" : {
            "_id" : {
              "timestamp" : 1610817549,
              "date" : 1610817549000
            },
            "firstname" : "test1first",
            "lastname" : "test1last",
          },
          "textScore" : 5.25
        } ],
        "score" : 5.25
      } ],
      "ok" : 1.0
    }
```

MappedResults:

```
[ {
  "reviews" : [ {
    "id" : "6003201f98afbc730e4f58eb",
    "some_point" : "something",
    "placeId" : null,
    "userId" : null,
    "date" : "Sat Jan 16 18:19:27 CET 2021",
    "textScore" : 5.25
  } ],
  "id" : "ibis Heidelberg, Willy-Brandt-Platz 3, 69115 Heidelberg, Germany",
  "userId" : null,
  "user" : null,
  "score" : 5.25
} ]
```

Why are they different? The raw result is correct, but when it is mapped, the place and user objects are removed. How can I include them in the mappedResult, as well?

Answer (score 1):

`getMappedResults()` gives you the direct mapping to mapping class and aggregation result. See what is wrong here. When you take `getRawResult()`, for an example I will take only `place`

```
"place" : {
    "_id" : {
      "timestamp" : 1610817567,
      "date" : 1610817567000
    },
    "place_name" : "ibis Heidelberg, Willy-Brandt-Platz 3, 69115 Heidelberg, Germany",
    "country" : "Germany",
}
```

`place` is an **object** which has `_id`, `place_name` and `country`. But in your mapped class `Review`, you have only `placeId` which is not provided by result. So it cannot do the point to point mapping. What you can do is

```
class Place{
    ObjectId _id;
    String place_name;
    String country;
    //Constrtuctors, Getters, Setters
}
```

In your review class,

```
class Review{
    // other fields
    Place place;
}
```

You need to do the same to other objects or array also. This should work

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but my goal is exactly to reduce the redundancy and avoid saving the whole `Place` object inside `Review`. If I put the `place` inside `Review`, I don't need the unwind and lookup in my aggregation at all and the code works. I want to avoid just the placeid in my Review class and in my search, extract the place object using the id.

Comment: In this case what you can do is, You dont need to have an output class, get it in `BasicDbObject.class`, like `mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,
                mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Review.class), BasicDbObject.class)`. The you can cast to Document if needed.(In my case I have casted to Document in my project for few reasons). Then you can use `get()` to get the particular field and assign it to ReviewAggrResults's fields,

Comment: Thank you @varman, I got the same issue and I used another attribute to make my match and unwind operations